# i18n of URL in a java project

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, internationalization

I am trying to internationalise the urls of my web application. Basically I want to be able to  set the url of, let's say, a link to www.mysite.com/france/inscription when the preferred language is fr and www.mysite.com/signup when the preferred language is en.

Until now I have beenusing a jtsl choose to manually set the url:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pageContext.request.locale.language eq 'fr'}">
        <a class="trialButton" href="<c:url value="/france/inscription?type=0"/>"><fmt:message key='features_trial'/></a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a class="trialButton" href="<c:url value="/subscribe?type=0"/>"><fmt:message key='features_trial'/></a>                    
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Ideally I would like to be able to get a localised url directly from my resource bundle, I tried to do:

```
<a class="trialButton" href="<c:url value=<fmt:message key='features_trial_url'/>/>"><fmt:message key='features_trial'/></a>
```

But eclipse doesn't accept it.

Do you know a way to do something like that?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't accept many things, but they work great in container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a JSP tag inside an attribute of another JSP tag. But all JSTL tags printing a value have an attribute `var` allowing to store the value inside an attribute instead of printing it. So you can simply use

```
<fmt:message key='features_trial_url' var"theUrl"/>
<a class="trialButton" href="<c:url value='${theUrl}'>"><fmt:message key='features_trial'/></a>
```